# items are not being added into firestore after using doc , setDoc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web

I am creating a Netflix clone website by using react and i am trying to add some data into fire store but for some reason it is not working and no error is being shown. I am using version 9 .I have restarted the server but nothing happened Sign in and sign up are working. Any help is appreciated , thanks . This is my code :

```js
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

function signUp(email, password) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
          savedShows: [],
    });
}
```

nothing is being shown in the console, there are no errors even after i tried to use catch(error)

and of course I have a separate env file for the keys

Comment: Please check your firebase rules if that user can write to the doc

Comment: I just added users into the firestore manually and it worked, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manually added a collection in firestore and now the data is being added. This should work if you have problems similar to that